# About an argument in Olsson's book

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, topos-theory, spectral-sequences, algebraic-stacks, cech-cohomology

The following picture is from *Algebraic spaces and stacks* (p.54) by Martin Olsson.
[image]

I don't understand how to conclude that $\alpha$ is induced by a nonzero class in the end.

It seems that there might be an exact sequence consists of edge maps like $E_2^{n0}\to H^n\to E_2^{0n}$ if there is a convergent first quadrant spectral sequence $E_2^{rs}\Longrightarrow H^{r+s}$, but this doesn't fall into the usual assumption for such an exact sequence to exist. Any ideas? Another way to explain Olsson's argument is also fine.

**Edit.** To summarize (by Minseon Shin's answer), the conclusion is: If in addition $E_{2}^{n-i,i} = 0$ for $0<i<n$, then we have an exact sequence
\begin{align*} E_{2}^{n,0} \to H^n \to E_{2}^{0,n}.\end{align*}
If moreover $E_{2}^{n-1-i,i} = 0$ for $0<i<n$, then we have an exact sequence
\begin{align*} 0\to E_{2}^{n,0} \to H^n \to E_{2}^{0,n}.\end{align*}
We might have a similar result for exactness on the right.

(This follows from the exact sequences $0\to F^nH^n=E_{\infty}^{n,0} \to H^n \to H^n/F^nH^n=H^n/F^1H^n=E_{\infty}^{0,n}\to 0$ (note $F^1H^n=F^nH^n$) and $E_{2}^{n,0}\to E_{\infty}^{n,0}\to 0, 0\to E_{\infty}^{0,n}\to  E_{2}^{0,n}$. If moreover $E_{2}^{n-1-i,i} = 0$ for $0<i<n$, then $E_{2}^{n,0}\xrightarrow{\cong} E_{\infty}^{n,0}$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness, the spectral sequence (2.3.14.1) mentioned is \begin{align*} E_{2}^{s,t} = \check{H}^{s}(\mathscr{X},\underline{\mathscr{H}}^{t}(F)) \implies H^{s+t}(C/X,F) \end{align*}

By minimality of $i_{0}$, we have $\underline{\mathscr{H}}^{i}(F) = 0$ for $0 < i < i_0$ so $E_{2}^{i_{0}-i,i} = 0$ for such $i$, thus we have an exact sequence \begin{align*} 0 \to E_{2}^{i_{0},0} \to H^{i_{0}}(C/X,F) \to E_{2}^{0,i_{0}} \;. \end{align*}

Comment: OK, I ignored that condition. So this will imply $\check{H}^{i_0}(\mathscr{X}, F)=E_2^{i_00} = H^{i_0}(C/X, F)$, right?

Comment: I made some edits (I don't think you can conclude the second equality).

Comment: Great, that clarify things!